# Why should Peek require 2.1 GB to install after upgrading to Mint 19?

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, gnome, mate-desktop

I was surprised upon upgrading from Linux Mint 18.3 to 19 that apps I had installed via the Software Manager were no longer available--I had thought that was one of the advantages of upgrading in-place.

Anyway, I went to reinstall some of these, and in most cases, that was no big deal.  However, when it came to Peek (the animated GIF capture tool) this is what I got:

[image]

So...what happened to Gnome, that it needs to reinstall that?  I don't even have enough space left for something like that.  I thought MATE was based on GNOME, and on the main Mint login screen I have the option of a MATE or Xfce desktop--and they both work--so wouldn't that imply that GNOME is still available?

If so, why should I need to install another 2.1 GB of software to use one tiny, lightweight tool that worked fine under MATE in Mint 18.3?  If not, can you explain what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peek is packaged as a Flatpak and not a deb package like the majority of linux applications. Flatpak apps bundle a lot of stuff with them like `org.gnome.Platform` which is quite large. It's possible when you updated mint the version of `org.gnome.Platform` was removed or peek changed the version it needs and has to download a new one.

Comment: So I may have GNOME already, but not its platform in Flatpak format?

Comment: Yes, the dependencies of a flatpak app using org.gnome.Platform will be different but should iirc be shared with other flatpaks.